# How to make Crestfallen Saulden not hostile towards me?

Tags: dark-souls-2

So i attacked him, and now he won't let me join his conventant, because hes attacking me every time any way to make him stop. he even attacked me while i was near the majula bonfire.

Answer (score 3):

Journey to Brightstone Cove Tseldora, which you can find past the Doors of Pharros. After you defeat Prowling Magus and the Congregation, you'll exit the church. Immediately turn left and you'll find a ladder. Go up the ladder and you'll find an NPC.

**DO NOT ATTACK THIS NPC OR YOU WILL BE UNABLE TO RESET NPC AGGRO**.

Talk to this NPC and you can spend 1,000 souls per soul level and gain forgiveness. This will reset all NPC aggro, but it does not reset your sin level.

Comment: "Per soul level"... interesting. So I could be level 10, and only have to pay 10,000 souls?